# creating WPF animation that executes code after each value update during animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, user-controls

I need a way to execute code after each iteration of an animation value change.  This code will have access to the 'new' layout of the control being animated before that control is drawn

For example, I have a "Length" dependency property being animated in a storyboard.  It updates the dimensions of a userControl, A (both its length and height via bindings).  During the animation, after each value update to Length, I have a method that I'd like to execute that modifies the content of another userControl, B.  The trick is, this method must have access to the new layout dimensions of userControl A before A is visually drawn, such that when the rendering finally takes place, both A and B have changed together from the user's perspective.  I've tried using the PropertyChangedCallback for the Length dependencyProperty, but this appears to be too late because the controls initially (briefly) appear out of sync to the user.  Ideally it would be something like:

- set Length dependency property value
- somewhere call UpdateLayout on UserControl A so new dimensions are calculated
- my method gets called before usercontrol A is rendered
- userControl B is modified
- finally everything is rendered to screen

My literal problem is much more complex so I won't provide code, and this is the precise problem I'd like to solve so I'm just looking for ideas, not alternatives

Comment: In my experience I believe it would be easier to include control B in the storyboard even if you had to do this programmatically.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem.  The method that controls usercontrol B has to have access to the new measurements of usercontrol A before A becomes visible.  Can't do that in a dual animation storyboard.  This is a deceivingly tricky problem

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to use the SizeChanged event instead of the PropertyChangedCallback event.  In SizeChanged, I have both old and new measures, and it hasn't been drawn yet.  Perfect.